# How do you prove the sequence $x_n = (\frac{n}{2})^n$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do you prove the sequence $x_n = (\frac{n}{2})^n$ diverges?

Here is my attempt:

Suppose $x_n \to L$. This means $(\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists N \in \mathbb{N}) (\forall n>N)|x_n-L| < \epsilon$

Assume $n > N$

Then $|x_n-L| < \epsilon$

$|(\frac{n}{2})^n-L| < \epsilon$

$|(\frac{n}{2})^n-\frac{2L}{2}| < \epsilon$

At this point I am stuck. I'm trying to arrive to a contradiction, but I'm unable to.

Comment: My attempt:

If $x_n = \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n$, then $x_{n+1} = \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^{n+1} = \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \ge \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) = x_n \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n+1}{2} = \infty$, we can see that the sequence diverges.

Comment: Why don't you try to calculate a few values of $x_n$ and see what happens?

Comment: Observe that $x_n\ge 1$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any sequence which is unbounded is divergent. Note that $(n/2)^{n}>n/2$ for $n>2$. Then if we pick any M, $n = 2M$ will have $(n/2)^{n}>n/2=M$. Therefore, the sequence is unbounded and divergent.

Comment: $(n/2)^{n}<n/2$ is false

Comment: Apologies. The inequalities were reversed. But the reasoning is valid.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I think that was clearly a typo. The answer could be worded better, but it doesn't deserve a negative score...

Comment: @mathbeing I reversed the minus

Comment: @EugenCovaci Glad to hear. I like your profile pic btw! =)

Answer (score 5):

Convergent sequences must be bounded. So simply show that your sequence is unbounded. For this you can use
$$\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^n \geq \frac{n}{2}.$$